# Scope of nested function declaration in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, scope, language-lawyer

```
namespace X {
    void f();
}

void X::f() {
    void g();
    g();
}
```

Have I declared `::g`, or `X::g`?

clang 3.5 will compile and link this if I add a definition of `X::g`:

```
namespace X {
    void f();
}

void X::f() {
    void g();
    g();
}

void X::g() { }
```

gcc 4.9.1 rejects the definition with the message:

> error: ‘void X::g()’ should have been declared inside ‘X’

but if I define `g` in the global namespace instead, gcc seems to change it's mind and complain about the opposite:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "X::g()", referenced from:
>       X::f()     in ccABCDEF.o
> ```

Because it is also illegal to declare `void ::g()` inside of `f`, it seems that it isn't possible to have a function-scope forward declaration of global function in a namespace function. Am I missing something? What exactly are the scoping rules here?

<sub>g++ (GCC) 4.9.1; Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function declarations at block scope have linkage. [basic.link]/6:

> The name of a function declared in block scope and [..] have linkage.

But such block scope declarations with linkage do not introduce any names into enclosing namespaces. [basic.link]/7:

> When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found
>   to refer to some other declaration, then that entity is a member of
>   the innermost enclosing namespace. **However such a declaration does not
>   introduce the member name in its namespace scope.**

You have therefore neither declared `::g` nor `X::g`. Defining it via

```
void X::g() {}
```

is ill-formed.